# Need SQL server query to get periods

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have following table:
where each Member has one col1 value per day.
I need to get the periods where col1 is zero for each member.

```
Member_ID   | col1            | Date         
ADavis      | 0               | 11-10-2013    
ADavis      | 0               | 11-11-2013   
ADavis      | 0               | 11-12-2013    
DSmith      | 1               | 11-10-2013    
DSmith      | 0               | 11-11-2013    
FRowden     | 0               | 11-10-2013     
FRowden     | 0               | 11-11-2013    
ADavis      | 1               | 11-13-2013   
ADavis      | 0               | 11-14-2013    
DSmith      | 1               | 11-12-2013    
DSmith      | 1               | 11-13-2013    
FRowden     | 1               | 11-12-2013    
FRowden     | 0               | 11-13-2013
```

output

```
Member_ID   | Start_date      | End_date    
ADavis      | 11-10-2013      | 11-12-2013  
ADavis      | 11-14-2013      | 11-14-2013  
DSmith      | 11-11-2013      | 11-11-2013  
FRowden     | 11-10-2013      | 11-11-2013  
FRowden     | 11-13-2013      | 11-13-2013
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use differences of `row_numbers()` :

```
select Member_ID, min(date), max(date)
from (select *, row_number() over (partition by Member_ID order by date) seq1,
                row_number() over (partition by Member_ID, col1 order by date) seq2
      from table t
      ) t
where col1 = 0
group by Member_ID, (seq1 - seq2);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can observe that if you subtract a sequential number from the date, then you'll have a constant value where the dates are sequential.

This gives the insight needed to bring together the sequential days:

```
select member_id, min(date), max(date
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by member_id order by date) as seqnum
      from t
      where col1 = 0
     ) t
group by member_id, dateadd(day, -seqnum, date);
```